# I can't combine 2 linq queries into one return. How can I do it?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to this stuff so I don't know much yet. I want to do 2 linq queries and I need to return them as a result. But I can't. Can you help me?

Linq query:

```
protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{

    var Orders = (from i in arkadas.AllWaitingOrdersReturns
                  join r in arkadas.WebOrdersNews on i.OrderId equals r.ID
                  where i.InvoiceNameSurname != null
                  select new
                  {
                      r.ID,
                      r.Email,
                      i.OrderNumber,
                      i.InvoiceNameSurname,
                      i.CustomerOrderCount,
                      i.ItemStockCode,
                      i.ProductName,
                      i.Publisher,
                      i.OrderDate,
                      i.RayonName,
                      i.OrderSystem,
                      i.OrderAmount,
                      i.SalesPrice,
                      i.CurrencyCodeName,
                      i.WebStock,
                      i.YuvaStock,
                      i.WebBDR,
                      i.PNRStock,
                      i.ATStock,
                      i.PublisherStock,
                      i.ORStock,
                      i.TotalStock
                  }).ToList();


    DateTime now = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

    TotalAmount.Text = "Bugün Siparişler Toplam Ürün Sayısı : " + Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate >= now).Sum(x => x.OrderAmount).ToString();

    TotalLine.Text = "Bugün Sipariş Sayısı : " + Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate >= now).GroupBy(x => x.OrderNumber).ToList().Count.ToString();

    LastTotalAmount.Text = "Bugünden Önceki Siparişler Toplam Ürün Sayısı : " + Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate < now).Sum(x => x.OrderAmount).ToString();

    LastTotalLine.Text = "Bugünden Önceki Sipariş Sayısı : " + Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate < now).GroupBy(x => x.OrderNumber).ToList().Count.ToString();

    e.Result = Orders;
}
```

What I'm doing is placing the incoming orders on the screen. But I need to write another query. And I need to display the incoming results on the same screen.

So I need to add another linq query like:

```
    var HepOrders = (from i in arkadas.AllWaitingOrdersReturns
                    join r in arkadas.HepsiBuradaWebOrdersNews on i.OrderId equals r.ID
                    where i.InvoiceNameSurname != null
                    select new
                    {
                        r.ID,
                        r.Email,
                        i.OrderNumber,
                        i.InvoiceNameSurname,
                        i.CustomerOrderCount,
                        i.ItemStockCode,
                        i.ProductName,
                        i.Publisher,
                        i.OrderDate,
                        i.RayonName,
                        i.OrderSystem,
                        i.OrderAmount,
                        i.SalesPrice,
                        i.CurrencyCodeName,
                        i.WebStock,
                        i.YuvaStock,
                        i.WebBDR,
                        i.PNRStock,
                        i.ATStock,
                        i.PublisherStock,
                        i.ORStock,
                        i.TotalStock
                    }).ToList();
```

After all, it should return with a single return. How can I do this?

Comment: Tried [.Concat(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Now I tried what you said but it didn't work. This is how i did it After I wrote my Linq queries as you say :                                                                                                         
  var Order = Orders.Concat(HepOrders).ToList();                                                       but it didn't work, it only gets the results from the first query, that is, it takes the orders query. @JonasH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join them in the same colelction, you could use .Union:
Order = Orders.Union(HepOrders).ToList();
If you need independent lists, you can return an object with 2 properties.